# Laravel 5.2.x test click link with a body having special characters

Tags: php, testing, laravel-5, click, delimiter

How can a link be tested if its body has special characters like "@"?

#### Example:

```
<a href="foo.php">foo@foo.com</a>
```

```php
public function foo()
{
    $this->visit('/foo')
         ->click('foo@foo.com');
}
```

#### Error output:

```
Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: Expected selector, but <delimiter "@" at 7> found.
```

I also tried to escape the "@" sign:

```php
public function foo()
{
    $this->visit('/foo')
         ->click('foo\@foo.com');
}
```

#### Error output:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Could not find a link with a body, name, or ID attribute of [foo\@foo.com].
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Laravel 5 are you using, as this doesn't happen if Laravel 5.2.x.

However, you can try escaping the `@` sign as follows:

```
public function foo()
{
    $this->visit('/foo')
         ->click('foo\@foo.com');
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using to display the link. The issue could be that the link doesn't actually exist.

Comment: I added the link source

Comment: @aleixfabra did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. No one has answered it.